# Copy missing rows from one table to another in sql server with stored procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have to tables in different databases (on the same server) that are identical. I need to transfer the data rows from the left database table to the right database table, but I only want to transfer the rows that aren't in the right database table already.

Is there a neat way of doing this?

Im using SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: How do you uniquelly identify one row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you can uniquelly identify a row with column `id`:

```
insert into databasename..tablename
select * from datababasename2..tablename2
where id not in (select id from databasename..tablename)
```

Comment: Almost there, one of the tables have two fields to make the row unique. where StoreName and PropertyName... but that doesn't work :/

Comment: Did resolve, where (StoreName not in (select StoreName from [LKEXTERN_EPI6R2].[dbo].[tblBigTableStoreInfo])
and PropertyName not in (select PropertyName from [LKEXTERN_EPI6R2].[dbo].[tblBigTableStoreInfo]))

Comment: @Trikks ugh, that is not the most efficient way to do it.