# Copy missing rows from one table to another with multi-column primary key

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

This topic is related to [Copy missing rows from one table to another in sql server with stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10885129/copy-missing-rows-from-one-table-to-another-in-sql-server-with-stored-procedure) but this time the problem is a bit more complex.

I have to tables in different databases (on the same server) that are identical. I need to transfer the data rows from the left database table to the right database table, but I only want to transfer the rows that aren't in the right database table already.

My table have four primary keys, see image

[image]

I'd like to use something like this

```
insert into [EXTERN_EPI6R2].[dbo].[tblBigTableReference]
select * from [EXTERN].[dbo].[tblBigTableReference]
where (
 pkId not in (select pkId 
  from [EXTERN_EPI6R2].[dbo].[tblBigTableReference]) 
 and PropertyName not in (select PropertyName 
  from [EXTERN_EPI6R2].[dbo].[tblBigTableReference]) 
 and IsKey not in (select IsKey 
  from [EXTERN_EPI6R2].[dbo].[tblBigTableReference])
 and [Index] not in (select [Index] 
  from [EXTERN_EPI6R2].[dbo].[tblBigTableReference])
)
```

But, that wont work since the stacking of the conditions is wrong in some way.

Im using SQL Server 2008 R2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your query is not correct because your various conditions can be matched on different rows.

```
insert into [EXTERN_EPI6R2].[dbo].[tblBigTableReference]
select * from [EXTERN].[dbo].[tblBigTableReference] AS s
where NOT EXISTS 
(
  SELECT 1 FROM [EXTERN_EPI6R2].[dbo].[tblBigTableReference] AS d
  WHERE d.pkId = s.pkId 
  AND d.PropertyName = s.PropertyName
  AND d.IsKey = s.IsKey
  AND d.[Index] = s.[Index] -- terrible column name
);
```

But this begs the question - why are all four of these columns part of the key? Is `pkId` not enough? If it isn't, it sure has a strange and incorrect name.